# Handle lambda-lists in method defining macros

Tags: lambda, macros, common-lisp

for example I want to get all variables from a lambda-list to define a macro:

```
(defmacro my-defun (name lambda-list &body body &aux (fname (gensym)))
  `(progn
     (defun ,fname ,(all-vars lambda-list)
       ,@body)
     (defun ,name ,lambda-list
       (,fname ,@(all-vars lambda-list)))))
```

are there some functions to do this or or other things to handle easier with lambda-lists, or is there no easier way than writing functions like this:

```
(defun all-vars (lambda-list)
  (mapcar (lambda (cons) (if (consp cons) (car cons) cons))
          (remove-if (lambda (symbol) (and (symbolp symbol)
                                           (char= (char (symbol-name symbol) 0) #\&)))
                     lambda-list)))
```

Comment: Rather than checking whether the first character of a variable is #\&, you could check whether the symbol is in [**lambda-list-keywords**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v_lambda.htm).

Comment: Even then, you have to watch out for correct syntax and other subtle points: `lambda-list-keywords` has more symbols than the ones allowed in a function's lambda list, the order matters, `&optional` and `&key` arguments may be a cons, and they differ in syntax, `&aux` aren't really parameters, etc.

Comment: @PauloMadeira That's absolutely right, especially about the &aux variables.  However, since the macro expansion includes a `(defun ,name ,lambda-list ...)`, the implementation will already have to check the correctness of the lambda list, so checking isn't quite as important in *this particular case*.

Answer (score 2):

This approach *is* sort of what you have to do, or need to find a library that already implements it.  There are libraries out there that handle lambda-list parsing (and every implementation has to do it, at least internally).  It's not usually too hard, just tedious.

That said, your implementation of **all-vars** isn't quite correct.  The full specification for keyword arguments in [ordinary lambda lists](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_da.htm) is:

```
[&key {var | ({var | (keyword-name var)} [init-form [supplied-p-parameter]])}* [&allow-other-keys]]
```

That means you can, e.g.,

```
(defun (&key ((:long-keyword-name x) "EX" xp))
  ...)
```

When you do **(if (consp cons) (car cons) cons)**, you'd get **(:long-keyword-name x)** back, not **x**.

Here's a version that I *think* works, but haven't tested extensively:

```
(defun lambda-list-variables (lambda-list)
  "Returns, in order, the variables declared in an ordinary lambda list,
but doesn't check that the lambda-list is actually legal."
  (labels ((ll-keyword-p (x)
             (member x lambda-list-keywords))
           (to-var (x)
             (if (symbolp x)
                 x             ; required, optional, rest, key, and aux 
                 (destructuring-bind (var &rest init-and-supplied) x
                   (declare (ignore init-and-supplied))
                   (if (listp var)
                       (second var)     ; key vars
                       var)))))         ; optional, key, and aux vars
    (remove-if #'ll-keyword-p
               (mapcar #'to-var lambda-list))))
```

```
CL-USER> (lambda-list-variables
          '(a b 
            &optional c (d 'dee) (e 'ee e-p)
            &rest f
            &key
            g
            (h 'aitch)
            (i 'eye i-p)
            ((:jay j))
            ((:kay k) 'kay)            
            ((:ell l) 'ell l-p)
            &aux 
            m
            (n 'en)))
;=> (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N)
```

Answer (score 1):

So many times I write a function like this only to find out it is already in the alexandria library.

```
(ql:quickload :alexandria)
```

And then

```
CL-USER> (alexandria:parse-ordinary-lambda-list '(a b c &optional x &key (ham 1 used-ham)))
```

returns

```
(A B C)
((X NIL NIL))
NIL
(((:HAM HAM) 1 USED-HAM))
NIL
NIL 
T
```

Comment: doesn't work for method lambda lists :(. but maybe I should use alexandria more often.

Comment: @cl-porky11: bummer. I'm sorry that I didnt test it with methods